# Executing (sudo) subcommands using Plink

Tags: powershell, ssh, command-line, putty, plink

I am trying to command Linux machine from Window PowerShell. The commands are dependent on the fail/pass of the commands before. Therefore, I have to put all the commands together. I have tried multiple ways of putting commands together but at the ends I only receive the output of the first command.

```
PS C:\Users\sams> plink -ssh -l username -pw root username@10.223.26.34 -t
      "sudo -i && cd /root/docker/storm-supervisor/ && ./stop-all.sh"
```

The actual result:  Only receives the output of the first command.

Expected result: Receives output of the final command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> sudo -i && cd /root/docker/storm-supervisor/ && ./stop-all.sh
> ```

Try your command in Linux shell. It won't work either. It will execute an elevated shell and wait for you to type commands. Only after you leave `sudo` shell, it will run the other commands (using the original account).

The `cd` and `./stop-all.sh` are sub-commands of the `sudo`. So you have to treat them that way.

- Best way is to provide the commands on `sudo` commandline:

  ```
  sudo "cd /root/docker/storm-supervisor/ && ./stop-all.sh"
  ```

  But that will probably require modifications of the `sudoers` file. Though it's the right way.
- Or you will need to feed the commands to `sudo` input:

  ```
  echo "cd /root/docker/storm-supervisor/ && ./stop-all.sh && exit" | sudo
  ```
- Or feed everything to Plink input:

  ```
  (
    echo cd /root/docker/storm-supervisor/
    echo ./stop-all.sh
  ) | plink -ssh -l username -pw root username@10.223.26.34 -t sudo -i
  ```
- Or even:

  ```
  (
    echo sudo -i
    echo cd /root/docker/storm-supervisor/
    echo ./stop-all.sh
  ) | plink -ssh -l username -pw root username@10.223.26.34 -t
  ```

Comment: Thank you, that helped.