# How to pass multiple commands to Shell function in VBA using putty?

Tags: excel, linux, vba, shell, putty

Am trying to connect to Linux server using VBA shell command. Am not able to execute multiple commands in it.

I have the below code in my VBA script, and the command file which has the list of commands

```
Private Sub main_function()

    cmd = "C:\putty.exe -t -ssh username@servername.com -pw password -P 22 -m c:\cmd.txt"
    retval = Shell(cmd, vbMaximizedFocus)

End Sub
```

```
sudo to user
cat > filename.txt
sh shellfile.sh
```

I want to execute all the listed commands in the cmd.txt file but am not able to execute any command from the cmd.txt file, the code just logs in to the linux and exits.

Comment: Does that putty command line work if run directly in cmd ?

Comment: Indeed, your command-line won't work even standalone. This is not a Excel/VBA question.

Comment: Also, don't use PuTTY to automate commands. Use Plink (part of PuTTY package).

Comment: And then see, [Executing (sudo) subcommands using Plink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432962/850848).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a batch file that works without using VBA then use the code you have above to simply call the batch file. Your issue is currently not related to VBA.

See this post on how to make a batch file to login to a server w/ Putty.

https://superuser.com/questions/1278434/create-a-batch-file-or-shortcut-to-putty-ssh-that-opens-a-session-and-runs-a-c

Eg: I just test and this worked fine

```
Private Sub main_function()

    cmd = "C:\test.cmd"
    retval = Shell(cmd, vbMaximizedFocus)

End Sub
```

Make sure your batch works when you double click it, then call via VBA.