# Run .bat file that starts Putty and call .sh script

Tags: linux, batch-file, putty

I`ve created a .bat file to open the connection on Putty:

```
putty.exe -ssh IP -l "user" -pw "password" -m C:\my\Test\dir\commands.txt -t
```

And then I run some commands

```
echo "password" | sudo -S ; ls ; "etcetera etcetera" ; script.sh ; sleep 10s
```

But when I run the script 'script.sh' it tells me: 'Command not found'.

If I run the commands manually instead, it works perfectly. I think there is some problem in running the script remotely, is there any way to solve the problem?

**EDIT**

I modified the .bat file like this:

```
plink.exe -ssh IP -l "user" -pw "password" -m C:\my\Test\dir\commands.txt -t
```

and the command file in this way:

```
(
echo "password" | sudo -S
ls
script.sh 
)
```

but it still says "command not found".

I have also tried "/usr/local/bin/script.sh" ma it says "permission denied", so maybe it is related to that?
But in case it is why "manually" I can run it in both ways?

**RE-EDIT**

Something was wrong with the first commands, so the password was not taken into account.
However, the command.txt file now looks like this:

```
(
sudo -S <<< "password" ls
sudo -i 
cd /tmp
chmod +x file
./file
script.sh
)
```

But unfortunately it seems that after the password has been taken another command cannot be taken.

So the output is now as follows:

***plink.exe -ssh IP -l "user" -pw "password" -m C:\my\Test\dir\commands.txt -t
Access granted. Press Return to begin session.
Password: root:~#***
and don`t continue.

**SOLVED**

I modified the command.txt like this:

```
(
sudo -S <<< "password" ls
sudo -i -- bash -c 'cd /tmp && chmod +x file && ./file && script.sh '
)
```

and it works

Comment: Use PLINK instead.

Comment: Are you sure that `echo "password" | sudo -S ; ls ; "etcetera etcetera" ; script.sh ; sleep 10s` like this  (as a single line) works when you *"run the commands manually"*? I'm sure it does not. You instead execute each command on a separate line, right? See [Executing (sudo) subcommands using Plink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432962/850848).

Comment: even with plink I have the same problem. But is not a matter of all the instruction in one line I think, it is just I can`t run the "script.sh", all the other commands work with this procedure

Comment: hmmm....actually maybe it is working.. Thanks. But when I run the script manually there is an output like "Operation ended". And now I can`t see it. It is possible that is related to my script?

Comment: What *"is working"*? Show us your current code and how exactly does it behave. We need [mcve].

Comment: Please, show the contents of `script.sh`.  I'm pretty sure it has a starting line something like `#!/bin/bash` and probably you are running the command in a place where `bash` is not in `/bin` (but in `/usr/local/bin`, for example)

Comment: After your edit: Read *again carefully* my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432962/850848 – your `commands.txt` does not address the fact that not all your commands are top-level commands. Some of them are subcommands of `sudo`.

Comment: You may want to copy-paste the working solution to an answer, thereby answering your own question.